# iPhone:TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method issue

Tags: iphone

I am facing a crashing problem in cellForRowAtIndexPath tableview delegate method

```
@interface EventListView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 

IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
NSMutableArray  *arr_EventValues,*arr_Event_Details;
NSMutableArray  *arr_EventListDetails;

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *arr_EventValues,*arr_EventListDetails, *arr_Event_Details; 
@property(nonatomic, retain)UITableView *tblView;

- (void)viewDidLoad  
{
     appdelegate = (VibesGuideAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     ViewCalendar = [[CalendarView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
     self.arr_Event_Details = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
     self.arr_EventValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [super viewDidLoad];
}

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     if ([self.arr_EventListDetails count] > 0)
     {
         return [self.arr_EventListDetails count];
     }
    return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    // ------------------------------- Custom cell ------------------------------
    Customcell  *cell = (Customcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     cell = [[[Customcell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

     cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";    
     return cell;
 }
```

* -[EventListView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x60e01b0  and I used tableview from xib and set all connections and also got arrayvalues in numberOfRowsInSection in method but in cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not called so please give me idea my issue....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think u release some where your object

Comment: no i am not release object so any idea??

Comment: put your code here then we check it

Comment: if u use custom cell why r u write their cell.textLabel.text use your custom label. this create problem. and use custom cell in write way

Comment: set the delegate and datasource for your tableview. As you are using it from the same class. Set those to self

Answer (score 2):

At first it seems your some variable gets released. Make sure you have properly allocated it. If you have declared `@property` for it you better use the variable as `self.variable`. You can use `retain` and in case of IOS 5 `strong` in property declaration.

Just to be sure you can track if any variable gets released via setting `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES`. With zombies enabled, messages to deallocated objects will no longer behave strangely or crash in difficult-to-understand ways, but will instead log a message and die in a predictable and debugger-breakpointable way. You can set NSZombieEnabled by the following steps.

Select Product from the menu bar above. Keep alt/option pressed and select "Test..." or "Run...". Go to the Arguments tab, and add NSZombieEnabled YES in the "Environment Variables" section.

Answer (score 2):

Your **tableview itself is already released** - the error message says that you send the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** message to a deallocated instance of the table view - so your problem lies somewhere in not retaining or releasing the **EventListView** and cannot be seen in the code displayed here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

> Table DataSource and delegate is set or not.
>   Used array in cellForRowAtIndexPath is properly set with property and synthesized as well used with self. name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dequeue the cell and then create a new one. This is not a good practice, if you are able to dequeue a cell you should not create a new one. You should have something like this:

```
 Customcell  *cell = (Customcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if(cell == nil)
 {
     cell = [[[Customcell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 }
```

fix this and let me know if you are still running on the same problem.